# Android - Layout stay at the current fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment

When I run my apps, everything works fine until I need to fragment to be replaced with another fragment. When user clicked one of the item on the listview, it should open the new layout(new fragment). But for now, nothing happened when I clicked on the item

This is my onCreate method

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);


        JsonArrayRequest tournamentReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());

                        // Parsing json
                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                            try {

                                JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                Tournament tournament = new Tournament();
                                tournament.setTitle(obj.getString("title"));
                                tournament.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("image"));
                                tournament.setDate(((Number) obj.get("tdate"))
                                        .doubleValue());
                                // Genre is json array
                                JSONArray categoryArry = obj.getJSONArray("category");
                                ArrayList<String> category = new ArrayList<String>();
                                for (int j = 0; j < categoryArry.length(); j++) {
                                    category.add((String) categoryArry.get(j));
                                }
                                tournament.setCategory(category);

                                // adding tournament to tournament array
                                TournamentList.add(tournament);

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            }
        });

    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(tournamentReq);
        }
```

This is my onCreateView and OnSelectionChanged method in

> TournamentFragment

```
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tournament, container, false);
        listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);

        if (rootView.findViewById(R.id.frag_tour) != null){

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            // Create an Instance of Fragment
            TournamentFragment tFragment = new TournamentFragment();
            tFragment.setArguments(getActivity().getIntent().getExtras());
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.frag_tour, tFragment)
                    .commit();
        }}return rootView;
}

    public void OnSelectionChanged(int versionNameIndex) {

    DescriptionFragment descriptionFragment = new DescriptionFragment();
    descriptionFragment.setArguments(getActivity().getIntent().getExtras());

    if (descriptionFragment != null){
        descriptionFragment.setDescription(versionNameIndex);
    } else {
        TournamentFragment tFragment = new TournamentFragment();

        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, tFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}
```

> fragment_description.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:id="@+id/fragment_container">

 <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="This is where each individual description will appear"
    android:id="@+id/version_description"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:gravity="center"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

So far, I had tried different kind of solution answered here in stackoverflow but still can't solve my problem.
Can someone help me understand this?

Comment: `R.id.drawer_layout`... Are you sure this is part of `activity_main2.xml`?

Comment: @cricket_007 yes

Comment: Why are you using `replace` in `onCreate`, shouldn't you just use `add` since there is no Fragment yet?

Comment: And you aren't replacing a Fragment in a Fragment here. You are replacing a Fragment in an Activity.

Comment: @cricket_007 I see. I must be confused by the different tutorial. So should I put the code inside onCreate method in TournamentFragment(the fragment that I want to be replace)?

Comment: Fragments generally use `onCreateView`, not `onCreate`. Also, `fragment_description.xml` does **not** contain `"@+id/drawer_layout"`, so that would explain your error. Also, nested Fragments is generally a poor design, anyway, but you would want to use `getChildFragmentManager()`

Comment: @cricket_007 I edit my post. Can you please check it?

Comment: You typically shouldn't use nested Fragments, so I'm not sure what you're asking for... You ran layout is the same because `rootView.findViewById(R.id.frag_tour` is always going to be null... That xml doesn't contain that id you're trying to find

Comment: @cricket_007 frag_tour is the id for fragment_tournament.xml

Comment: You're missing that xml file in the question

Answer (score 0):

Use below code

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .detach(contentFragment) // detach the current fragment
                .attach(contentFragment) // attach fragment that you want.
                .commit();
```

Comment: Is it on onCreate inside fragment class that I want to replace?

Comment: @nao `getSupportFragmentManager()` can only be called from a `FragmentActivity` subclass, not a Fragment

Answer (score 0):

Try to call through

```
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fragment_container, tFragment)
            .fragmentTransaction
            .commit();
```